# Drift current and diffusion current in depletion region of diode at equilibrium

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, material-science

The diffusion current for a diode at the edge of the depletion region is $I_D=I_S(e^{qV_A/VT}-1)$. Under an unbiased condition$(V_A=0)$ at equilibrium, $I_D$ will be $0$. The drift current should be equal to the diffusion current in opposite direction at equilibrium so drift current should also be equal to $0$. In the image below and in many other textbooks, drift current is not zero in the depletion region and it stays constant as applied voltage $V_A$ changes so now I am confused and I am not sure if drift current is actually equal to $0$ or not. I am also curious if drift current is included in a typical graph of current density under forward bias i.e. 2nd graph

[image]
[image]